# Taxonomy Term Permissions

Tags: 7, users, taxonomy-terms

i tried to use [Taxonomy Term Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/term_permissions)
module to set permissions on terms, but this module does not work.

After selecting the roles that i want to allow them selecting the specific term and saving the changes, nothing get saved, i tried also to search for a solution i found a version that worked in drupal 7, i replaced it with the first module.

this version has corrected to allow us to select the roles with saving the changes, but when i requested to create a node(go to create node page) the page did not open and show up a message that tell me an error happen in my site,

There is another module like that one above? or is there another way to set  permission on a terms?
thanks.

Comment: Did you look in your permission settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some other modules you can try:

[Taxonomy Access Control](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access)

[Taxonomy Access Control Lite](https://drupal.org/project/tac_lite)

A short but good tutorial for `Taxonomy Access Control` is available at [Control Who Can View Drupal Nodes: Taxonomy Access Control](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/taxonomy-access/)

Comment: u can use the dev version of Taxonomy Access Control if it's far more recent in comparision with the recommanded one